# TorchStudio cannot run

Tags: python, pytorch, torchstudio

I seen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNKTdMWO56w . Then I install TorchStudio. My PC: Windows 11 x64, Python 3.10 . I go to homepage of TorchStudio https://www.torchstudio.ai/ , then download. My log

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1265]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\donhu>python
Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

C:\Users\donhu>where python
C:\Users\donhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
C:\Users\donhu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

C:\Users\donhu>pip install torch
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Requirement already satisfied: torch in c:\users\donhu\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (1.13.1+cu117)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch) (4.4.0)

C:\Users\donhu>pip install torchvision
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in c:\users\donhu\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (0.14.1+cu117)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow!=8.3.*,>=5.3.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (9.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: torch==1.13.1 in c:\users\donhu\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from torchvision) (1.13.1+cu117)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->torchvision) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->torchvision) (1.26.14)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->torchvision) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->torchvision) (2.0.4)

C:\Users\donhu>pip install torchaudio
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Requirement already satisfied: torchaudio in c:\users\donhu\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (0.13.1+cu117)
Requirement already satisfied: torch==1.13.1 in c:\users\donhu\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from torchaudio) (1.13.1+cu117)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch==1.13.1->torchaudio) (4.4.0)

C:\Users\donhu>pip install torchtext
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting torchtext
  Downloading torchtext-0.14.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (1.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.9/1.9 MB 16.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchtext) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchtext) (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchtext) (4.64.1)
Requirement already satisfied: torch==1.13.1 in c:\users\donhu\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from torchtext) (1.13.1+cu117)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch==1.13.1->torchtext) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->torchtext) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->torchtext) (1.26.14)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->torchtext) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->torchtext) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tqdm->torchtext) (0.4.6)
Installing collected packages: torchtext
Successfully installed torchtext-0.14.1

C:\Users\donhu>pip install graphviz
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting graphviz
  Downloading graphviz-0.20.1-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 47.0/47.0 kB 1.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: graphviz
Successfully installed graphviz-0.20.1

C:\Users\donhu>where python
C:\Users\donhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
C:\Users\donhu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

C:\Users\donhu>
```

[image]

After I seen in console (CMD) show install finished, I press icon, but it show as when I no download.

[image]

then I try [image]

[image]

[image]

My install log https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/c3371e8c40b0524f8a500a12a90a1f5f#file-install-log-L542

How to install, then run Torch Studio success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do all the command line things as in the first screenshot. Just click "Install" in the dialog of your last screenshot.

See log

```
Installing Python in C:\Users\donhu\TorchStudio\python...
```

Choose Python.exe at this position.

[image]

Comment: When install Python at https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/c3371e8c40b0524f8a500a12a90a1f5f#file-install-log-L9 You should not request user choose Python.exe again by button `Select...` . It causes confusing. Your tool is great.